# WebClient DownloadData SocketException

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

This is a very popular topic here, and I have read at least twenty different stackoverflow, expertsexchange, codeproject "solutions", and they boil down to things like: proxy servers (which they assure me isn't being used), and other things that just don't help me.

I have an image that is sitting out on this server.  It can be publicly reached through a URL (I won't give that here, being this is a customer server).  **The URL that is exposed is through a Virtual Directory that is set up through IIS.**

I opened Visual Studio and created a new ASP.NET Web Application - and I made it an empty project, and added one WebForm to it.  Simple as simple can be.

The only code I added was to the WebForm Page_Load function:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            Uri myUri = new Uri(@"http://SERVER/folder/Image.bmp", UriKind.Absolute);
            byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(myUri);
        }
    }
```

That's it.  That's all I do.

Because that URL is publicly exposed, when I run it in Visual Studio.  It works.

Also, at work, I have a Web Server with IIS (The IIS that comes with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard - Service Pack 1).  I just copied my whole project folder (after I built for release), plopped it on inetpub/wwwroot/, went to IIS, added it as an Application (using annonymous access, and the Default App Pool).

Here, at work, no problem!  No errors.

Now, I do the same thing to their server.  Just take the whole folder.  Create an application, etc. etc.  .... and as soon as I get to the DownloadData piece of code I get an exception:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [redacted]:80 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [redacted]:80

Source Error:     

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace:        

[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [redacted]:80]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +8409635
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +611

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +365
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address) +111
   WebClientTest.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\[me!!!]\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebClientTest\WebClientTest\WebForm1.aspx.cs:18
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3811

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2053.0
```

So, to recap:

Simple project works in my debugging environment.  Check!
Works on my server at work.  Check!
Doesn't work on client server.  Not Check!

There has to be some explanation for this.  Obviously I can see the host.  So why, when they host this code, instead of me, does it fail to establish a connection?  Finding this information, or what can cause this, is surprisingly difficult.  It has to be some type of server setting, right?

Their server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

EDIT: I also want to mention that I can open a browser anywhere (my desktop, my VM which hosts my debugging environment, their server, etc.) and if I take that URL, the bitmap displays.  No problem.  As soon as IIS/ASP.NET get involved ... connections fail.  This is so discouraging.

**EDIT2:** I have a public facing cloud server, that has the same setup (same type of virtual directory, an image, etc).  So I added a second WebForm to this project.  Same code in PageLoad, this time pointing to my server for the image, instead of theirs.  That page works!  There's definitely something on their server that is causing this.  But what?

Comment: You are sure you could ping it from your application? if yes, Can you download it from the browser where you application is running without logging in?

Comment: I assure you with utmost confidence: that I can take that same URL from my code, put it in a browser on my machine, and the image will be displayed.  In fact, I'm remote into their machine, and can do it from their server too.  The image displays, no problem (and why they were suggesting it must be something we are doing in our code, since it "can be seen in the browser" no problem).

Comment: In fact, if I step through, I got the bytes.length of 254,934.  When I right-click properties on that image, the size is ... 248 KB (254, 934 bytes).  So I can see it through a browser, and I am downloading it, from my server, and my test environment.  It gets to their server -- and nothing!

Comment: Which user account or principal your app pool runs under?

Comment: For the app pool, we created a Local Account/Administrator.  And when you look at the Properties -> Security tab of the folder, on this server, it allows CREATOR OWNER, SYSTEM, Administrators, and Users.  The appPool itself is using Classic Managed Pipeline Mode and as I mentioned, that Administrator account as the Identity.

Comment: I'm on their server now.  I can look at anything, set anything, change anything.  I'm comparing everything I can to what I have on my server at work (app pool settings, IIS settings) - and I just don't see anything that much different.  Yet, here we are.

Comment: Actually, to be a bit clearer, the folder structure itself (to the image) is exposed through a Virtual Directory set up in IIS.  And when you look at the basic settings, it's "connect as" that same user we setup - the local Administrator.